# WiFi keeps dropping, but icon does not change to indicate a fault

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration

I have just moved my PC to upstairs in the house and moved from a wired, to a WiFi connection and I installed a TP-LINK Archer T9E AC1900 Dual Band Wireless PCI Express Adapter.

As the title says, the internet regularly just drops out and I have to wait 5/10 seconds for it to come back up but then within 20 seconds it will just drop out again. The icon does not change to indicate a problem.

I have updated the driver from the official website.
I am using windows 10 and turned off the power saving function.
Tried the various netsh and ipconfig.

Any help would be appreciated and I will provide any extra information as needed.

Comment: There are many possible causes of the issue, but the first thing to try is adjusting the WiFi router antenna for greatest signal, and then try another channel. See https://www.lifewire.com/wifi-channel-number-change-to-avoid-interference-818208

Comment: What is the RSSI of your wireless network connection at the new location?

Answer (score 0):

We can try to troubleshoot the issue as below:

1. Check if the antenna of the wireless network card is plugged in.
2. Can other wireless devices upstairs or downstairs use the wireless network normally? If this is the case, it may be caused by unstable wireless network signals. If other devices can use the wireless network normally, it may be a problem with the wireless network card driver or the wireless network itself.
3. It is recommended to move the computer and other wireless devices close to the router to see if they will frequently disconnect from the network.
   If other devices can use the wireless network normally, only the computer will be disconnected from the network, which may be a problem with the wireless network card driver or the wireless network itself.

Update the wireless network card driver through the official website of the wireless network card. if wireless network card driver is the latest, test the problem of the wireless network card itself.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the more technical answers:

The easiest way, really, without having to try all types of tools and learn new tech is to

> **move closer to the Access Point**.

Chances are high this will solve your problem - if it doesn't you've narrowed the possibilites. win/win

Answer (score -1):

Windows 10 has recently gained bad rep on forced drivers updates and frequent instability...remember to disable auto update of drivers via control panel or local group policy editor...

If you own an android device WifiAnalyzer can help you perform a site-survey, investigate neighboring interference and change channels accordingly...prefer 2,4GHz, although more heavily used, since it is stronger when signal meets interior walls etc...

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.

Comment: No answer actually answers the question...all answers provide helpful troubleshooting tips...